# from import のエラー

Tags: python, python3

`from import` をREPLで書き込み実行したのですがエラーが出てしまい解決方法がわかりません。また、2枚目の写真は一番エラーが少なかったものなのですがなぜエラーが出てしまったのかわかりませんでした。未熟でお恥ずかしいのですが教えていただけると幸いです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

1つ目はおそらく`vcomp140.dll`というdllが見つからない、というものでしょう。
[OpenMP ライブラリ リファレンス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/parallel/openmp/reference/openmp-library-reference?view=msvc-160)

何かの原因でそのdllがアンインストールされたとか、dllのサーチパスから外れたとかが考えられます。

Pythonのコマンドプロンプトを終了・再起動させてみるとか：

VC++の再頒布可能パッケージを入れ直してみるとか：
[最新のサポートされる Visual C++ のダウンロード](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/topic/2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0)

Pythonのscikit-learnをアンインストール/再インストールしてみるとか：
古い版かもしれませんが、こんな記事があります。
[Problem of install in windows #15899](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15899)
[Error: Missing vcomp140.dll #18088](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18088)

scikit-learnも含めて、インストールされているPythonの各モジュールをすべて最新版にupdateしてみてはどうでしょう？

色々試してみてください。

---

2つ目は`fromsklearn import datasets`ということで、単に`from`と`sklean`の間の空白が無いために発生しているのでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。できるまでいろいろ試してみます